# Graph is not displaying in Node Js Application

Tags: node.js, jsreport

I'm integrating JSReport in Node JSApplication. The JSReport uses several 3rd party api's to display chart etc. When I run JSReporn alone it works perfectly. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf9iM.png)

When i run This with Node JS application, It doesn't display the graph. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddT27.png)

Here i attached my code is on jsreport studio
Template is :

```
    <h1>{{country}}</h1>

    <canvas id='orders' style="margin-top:30px"></canvas>
    <table class="table striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>OrderID</th>
                <th>ShipAddress</th>
                <th>ShipCity</th>
                <th>ShipCountry</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each orders}}
            <tr>
                <td>{{OrderID}}</td>
                <td>{{ShipAddress}}</td>
                <td>{{ShipCity}}</td>
                <td>{{ShipCountry}}</td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.min.js'></script>

    <script>      
        var data = {{{toJSON this}}}
        Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
        var orders = document.getElementById("orders").getContext('2d');
        var chartObj = new Chart(orders, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: Object.keys(data.accumulatedOrders),
                datasets: [{
                    fillColor: 'blue',
                    label: "Orders in time",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(27,161,226,0.2)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(27,161,226,1)",
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(27,161,226,0.4)",
                    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(27,161,226,1)",
                    data: Object.keys(data.accumulatedOrders).map(function (o) {
                        return data.accumulatedOrders[o].value;
                    })
                }]

            },
            options: {
                animation: {
                    onComplete: function () {
                        // set the PDF printing trigger when the animation is done
                        // to have this working, the phantom-pdf menu in the left must
                        // have the wait for printing trigger option selected
                        //window.JSREPORT_READY_TO_START = true
                    }
                }
            }
        });


    </script>    


Script code is :

// custom server side script used to fetch data from remote REST API
var http = require('http');

function getOrders(country, cb) {
    http.get({
        hostname: 'services.odata.org',
        port: 80,
        path: `/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$filter=${encodeURI(`ShipCountry eq '${country}'`)}`,
    }, (result) => {
        var str = '';
        result.on('data', (b) => str += b);
        result.on('error', cb);
        result.on('end', () => cb(null, JSON.parse(str)));
    });
}

function beforeRender(req, res, done) {
    // the report parameter country can be send from the client API request
    req.data.country = req.data.country || 'France'
    getOrders(req.data.country, (err, json) => {        
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }

        var orders = json.value;
        var ordersByQuarter = {};

        orders.forEach((o) => {
            o.OrderDate = new Date(o.OrderDate);
            var key = o.OrderDate.getFullYear() + '/' + (o.OrderDate.getMonth() + 1);
            ordersByQuarter[key] = ordersByQuarter[key] || {
                value: 0,
                orderDate: o.OrderDate
            };
            ordersByQuarter[key].value++;
        });

        req.data.orders = orders;
        req.data.accumulatedOrders = ordersByQuarter;

        done();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your code it's hard to answer, but the answer is probably that the chart renders asynchronously and the report snapshot is being taken before it finishes.  If there's animation on the chart, turn it off.  If not, there are a few ways you can delay rendering to ensure it shows up.

Comment: i add my template and script code is having on jsreport studio